# firebase function Error: Cannot find module when serving locally, out of the blue on previously working project

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I haven't touched any firebase related files and I can't seem to figure out why exactly this has just started occuring, but I keep getting:

```
We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
   - It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.
   - You may be able to run "npm run build" in your functions directory to resolve this.
```

my firebase config file:

```
{
    "functions": {
        "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
        "source": "server"
    }
}
```

and my folder structure:

[image]

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "**/*spec.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src"]
}
```

Comment: Your error message says "(see above)".  What's above?  Did you run `npm run build` as it suggested?

Comment: @DougStevenson hi Doug, above is simply a stack trace for the error in the title: ```!  Error: Cannot find module 'reports-function\server'```

Comment: Why do you think that module isn't loading? There really isn't enough information here for us to know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I had by accident imported an uncompiled Typescript file from the parent project of the functions.

Typically that was a lib that should have been a package dependency.

Comment: it seems like a problem with multiple possible culprits, i'm hoping anyone stumbling across the question will be able to get some insight into where their potential problem lies -- have marked this as the solution as its weird marking your own answer as the solution

Comment: @SebastianG nah it aint weird bro. Do as you like. for me it's multiple. 

Let the users perhaps decide eventually. For now yours or mine, it's all good bro.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue in my tsconfig.json

Firebase will look in the package.json's main property to find your function code, in my case I had:

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
```

but index.js is outside the SRC folder and to get vscode to shut up about the tsconfig file I added that 'includes' property there that broke things.

Removing the includes/excludes from there works perfectly.

This mistake was easily identifiable from my screenshot and tsconfig that I had in my first post.

Comment: in my case i had to update output path- "main": "lib/src/index.js", in package.json

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to install `tslib` in the functions directory before they would deploy.

I'll be honest, I *don't* know why. In one of my projects I didn't see this issue at all. In both that project and this one, the compiled code references `tslib` all over the place.

This solution worked for me with `tslib@2.0.1`. I'm low-key worried that a new version of TypeScript might break things unexpectedly, but for now, this seems to work under `typescript@4.0.2`.

For context, firebase-tools kept giving me errors like this one:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs
```

In the cloud terminal, I found this message:

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error simply because I had not executed `npm run build`

However, I found it painful to keep running `npm run build` all the time.

So I added a watch script in the functions folder that automatically runs `npm run build` when any files in the functions folder change. This works really well when running firebase emulators locally.

The watch script looks like this:

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar')
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeout
  return function (...args) {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}

const exec = (cmd) => {
  try {
    const res = execSync(cmd)
    return {
      success: true,
      message: res.toString(),
      err: null
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      success: false,
      message: err.stderr.toString(),
      err
    }
  }
}

const build = () => {
  console.log('building')
  const res = exec('npm run build')
  if (res.success) {
    console.log('build success', res.message)
  } else {
    throw Error(res.err)
  }
}

const buildDebounced = debounce(build, 1000)

chokidar.watch('./src').on('all', () => {
  buildDebounced()
})
```

I had to make this change to .eslintrc.js

```
ignorePatterns: [
  '/lib/**/*',
  'watch.js'
]
```

To execute the watch script just run `node watch.js`

Optionally, to run the watch script in the background with the emulators running in the foreground I created a short bash script called `start.sh` as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd functions || exit
npm run build
# executes watch script in background and silences output
(node watch.js &) &> /dev/null
firebase emulators:start
```

To execute the bash script just run `start.sh`